# comparing number with special character

Tags: c, char, ascii, special-characters

Consider the following C-program:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main()
{
    char c;

    c = 65;
    if(c=='A') printf("condition true");
    return 0; 
}
```

As expected (since the ASCII code for A is 65 this program prints the statement "condition true").

Now consider the following C-program:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
int main()
{
    char c;

    c = 27;
    if(c==ESC) printf("condition true");
    return 0; 
}
```

Since the ASCII code for ESC is 27, I expected this program to print the statement "condition true", too. However, the program didn't even compile but gave back the following error message:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'ESC'
```

How can I check whether some number (e.g. 27) is the ASCII code for some special character (such as ESC, EOF, ...)?

Comment: These special characters are not defined, you can define them by yourself using `#define` directive:
`#define ESC 27`
Put it after `#include`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ESC` is not defined in C to be a special character nor *ESC*.  C does not even require ASCII, although that is by far the most common coding set used.

Create your own

```
#ifndef ESC
  #define ESC 27
#else
  #error prior esc definition
#endif

if (some_number == ESC) {
  puts("number is same as ASCII ESC");
}
```

---

Notice that `A` is not defined to be 65 either.

If code needs to test if a number is an ASCII A, use

```
#define ASCII_A 65
if (some_number == ASCII_A) {
```

If code needs to test if a number is an `'A'`, (Matches the *A* of the source coding set)

```
if (some_number == `A`) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Only certain special characters are defined by the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) in section 5.2.2:

- `\a`: alert
- `\b`: backspace
- `\f`: form feed
- `\n`: new line
- `\r`: carriage return
- `\t`: tab
- `\v`: vertical tab

If the special character is one of these, you can use one of the above escape sequences in a character constant (ex. `'\n'`) to compare against.